# Erro Data Report Group Footer VB6

Tags: mysql, visual-basic-6

Opa!

Preciso adicionar um campo a mais num relatório data report do vb6 como na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A conexão com o banco é feito via Driver ODBC 5.1 com banco MySQL.
Uso este SQL para geração do relatório:

```
SELECT *, venda.TotalS AS total_venda_agrupa, venda.totalc AS valor_total_venda, venda_forma_pagamento.descricao AS nome_forma_pagamento, vendaesc.QUANTIDADEprod as qtd, (vendaesc.QUANTIDADEprod * vendaesc.ValUniProd) As total_soma  FROM vendaesc,venda INNER JOIN venda_forma_pagamento ON venda_forma_pagamento.cod = venda.forma_pagamento where vendaesc.data='2016-03-30' AND venda.cod = vendaesc.venda   order by venda.cod
```

O que faz é apenas relacionar as tabelas e trazer os dados, coisa simples.

O novo campo é um RptFunction dos componentes do data report.
Antes de tentar adicionar este campo, o relatório não tinha nenhum Grupo Header/Footer, foi preciso adicionar para o novo campo não ficar na listagem de itens do relatório e sim abaixo de cada grupo de lista.

Ao adicionar este grupo, começou a dar este erro,

```
report section do not match data source
```

Algum sabe como solucionar isso, o que tem de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Tente adaptar para uso do SHAPE APPEND assim:

```
If RSTest Is Nothing Then
    Set RSTest = New ADODB.Recordset
End If
If RSTest.State = adStateOpen Then
    RSTest.Close
End If


'Two tables
SQL = "SHAPE {SELECT vendaesc.venda as venda,vendaesc.tipo as tipo,vendaesc.prod as prod, vendaesc.ValUniProd as valuniprod, vendaesc.QUANTIDADEprod as qtd, (vendaesc.QUANTIDADEprod * vendaesc.ValUniProd) As total_soma  FROM vendaesc} AS Level1 " & _
        "APPEND ({SELECT venda.forma_pagamento_detalhe_nome as forma_pagamento_detalhe_nome,venda.forma_pagamento_parcelas as forma_pagamento_parcelas, venda.TotalS AS total_venda_agrupa, venda.totalc AS valor_total_venda, venda_forma_pagamento.descricao AS nome_forma_pagamento from venda INNER JOIN venda_forma_pagamento ON venda_forma_pagamento.cod = venda.forma_pagamento where venda.cod = vendaesc.venda order by venda.cod } AS Level2 " & _
            "RELATE venda.cod to venda.cod)"

RSTest.Open SQL, gConexao, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
Set RptFPagamentoDetalhe.DataSource = RSTest


With RptFPagamentoDetalhe.Sections("Section1").Controls
    .Item("Text2").DataMember = "Level1"
    .Item("Text2").DataField = "venda"

    .Item("Text1").DataMember = "Level1"
    .Item("Text1").DataField = "tipo"

    .Item("Text3").DataMember = "Level1"
    .Item("Text3").DataField = "prod"

    .Item("Text4").DataMember = "Level1"
    .Item("Text4").DataField = "qtd"

    .Item("Text6").DataMember = "Level1"
    .Item("Text6").DataField = "ValUniProd"

    .Item("txtTotal").DataMember = "Level1"
    .Item("txtTotal").DataField = "total_soma"

    .Item("Text5").DataMember = "Level2"
    .Item("Text5").DataField = "nome_forma_pagamento"

    .Item("Text7").DataMember = "Level2"
    .Item("Text7").DataField = "forma_pagamento_detalhe_nome"

    .Item("Text8").DataMember = "Level2"
    .Item("Text8").DataField = "forma_pagamento_parcelas"
End With
```

Ta me retornando data filed empty